# Is there a way to set a parbox to a minimum height?

Tags: boxes

I'm looking for a way to make it so that my `\parbox`es keep a minimum height, similar to [CSS `min-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height), e.g.

```
\mhparbox{\textwidth}{3cm}{...}
```

would ensure that whatever text appears in place of `...`, the resulting box will at least take up 3cm of vertical space. Does a package to that effect exist or is there maybe a solution using `\savebox`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}



    \sbox{0}{\parbox{.5\textwidth}{one two three}}
    \ifdim\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0<3cm 
    \dp0\dimexpr3cm-\ht0\fi

    \fbox{\usebox{0}}


\end{document}
```

Comment: works like a charm! thanks very much indeed! google was of almost no help here, apparently not a very much researched topic in the LaTeX world, all the better there's one more solution for people to use!

Comment: Is it possible to get an approach for a minimum width?

Comment: @OSjerick sorry I can't guess what you mean (or rather I could guess several meanings) and anyway it is best not to ask new questions as comments on 2 year old questions. Please ask a new question with an example.

Answer (score 7):

This is a bummer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz\node[draw,minimum height=3cm,text width=0.5\textwidth,inner sep=1pt] {one two three\\four five six};

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution with `tcolorbox` package. For unbreakable boxes it's possible to define a `height from=height1 to height2` where `height1` defines the minimum height to be applied. If text doesn't fill the box it has `height1` but if the text is longer, the box uses the needed space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{%
    sharp corners, height from=3cm to 20cm, #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}
This is a short text
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to specify the optional argument `[height]` in the `\parbox` command like this: `\parbox[][<height>][t]{<width>}{ }`

[image]

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\fbox{\parbox[][3cm][t]{\textwidth}{This is a box.}}
The text is under this parbox.

\end{document}
```

---

For those who are interessted, here is what the other optional arguments do:

1: gives the position of the *parbox* with respect to surrounding material. Supported values: **c, m, t, b**. m: does the same as c.

3: gives the position of the text inside *parbox*. Supported values: **t, c, b, s**. s: stretch the text out verticually.

c: centered, t: top, b: bottom.