# Customizing beamer block height

Tags: beamer, block

I'm trying to specify a given height for a beamer block.
I tried to specify a new environment based on an example I found elsewhere on this forum (reproduced below), but failed miserably..
What I would like to do is to specify, each time, the height of the block (instead of its width).
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Andy

Example code:

```
\newenvironment<>{varblock}[2][.9\textwidth]{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{#1}
  \begin{actionenv}#3%
  \def\insertblocktitle{#2}%
   \par%
   \usebeamertemplate{block begin}}
{\par%
\usebeamertemplate{block end}%
\end{actionenv}}
```

Comment: May be this can help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215445/1952

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not what you want, but in case you don't find a better solution, [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) could help.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{warsaw}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tcolorbox}[beamer,title=tcolorbox,height=3cm]
Some text
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[beamer,title=tcolorbox,height=4cm, width=5cm]
Some text
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? If downvoters explain what's wrong with answers, authors can improve them.

Comment: The problem is what you already acknowledge "Probably not what you want". In Stack, it's a good practice to answer *exactly* the author question, to fulfil the author requirements and, potentially, the requirements of all the people that later will find the question and answer. Anyway, your solution works, and if it is not better way to do it, it's okay.