# beamer: Add Transparency to Elements of \titlepage

Tags: beamer

### Intro

- I want to spice my title page up by using a fancy background picture.
- Due to a bad contrast (text/picture) the readability is poor.
- I added a background color (`bg =`) to the elements of the `\titlepage` (see MWE).

### Questions

> 1. Is it possible to define the background color (`bg =`) with a
>      transparency level?
> 2. I figured out that `\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][rounded=true]` changes the text boxes but I couldn't add (--> error) transparency (e. g. `opacity=0.3`).
> 3. I do not understand why I need to add `[default]` to the `\setbeamertemplate{title page}` in order to apply the `rounded=true` (I don't need that when setting a color like in `\setbeamercolor`).
> 4. Is it possible to change the `width` of the boxes (other then increasing the margin locally)?

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

% Define Title Page
\title{Title of Presentation}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Dr. Manuel Kuehner}
\institute{Where I Work}
\date{\today}

\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=white,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{subtitle}{fg=white,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{author}{fg=white,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{institute}{fg=white,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{date}{fg=white,bg=black}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][rounded=true]

% Print Title Page
{ % Begin Group
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image.png}}%
\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
} % End Group

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Own Partial Solution

By adding `\pgfsetfillopacity{0.65}` just before the `\titlepage` command is kind of a manual solution (bus with some problems, see output).

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
\pgfsetfillopacity{0.65}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/317845/36296

Comment: @samcarter Thanks. I hope there is a easier/cleaner solution :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**: If you don't like the below answers, [define your own titlepage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22346/how-to-customize-titlepage-in-beamer) with semi-transpartent boxes of your own choice, [for example from the `tcolorbox` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233961/customizing-beamer-block-height/234068).

---

So if you would have asked "How to define a title page with semi-transparent blocks of variable size" you would have gotten a [more useful answer](http://danielfalster.com/blog/2013/06/18/a-nice-title-page-for-beamer-presentations/), but here are the answers to the questions you asked:

> 1. Is it possible to define the background color (`bg =`) with a
>      transparency level?

Never say never in latex, but it might involve rewriting `beamer` ...

> 2. I figured out that `\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][rounded=true]` changes the text boxes but I couldn't add (--> error) transparency (e. g. `opacity=0.3`).

The arguments used in the `titlepage` template (see `beamerinnerthemedefault.sty` for the definition) are passed on to `beamercolorbox`es, which have no parameter for transparency. So no big surprise that random arguments, which are not defined, do not work.

> 3. I do not understand why I need to add `[default]` to the `\setbeamertemplate{title page}` in order to apply the `rounded=true` (I don't need that when setting a color like in `\setbeamercolor`).

You need the `default`, because you are not setting your own content, you are just loading a predefined template called `default` (defined in `beamerinnerthemedefault.sty`) If you would set your own, you could use the same syntax you are used with colours:

```
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{%
    \begin{frame}
       bla
    \end{frame}
 }
```

> 4. Is it possible to change the `width` of the boxes (other then increasing the margin locally)?

Yes, there are several. See for example [Changing default width of blocks in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12550/changing-default-width-of-blocks-in-beamer)

> Your black line problem

The "problem" is that the top area and the body of the boxes overlap - this ensures, that there will be no ugly viewer artefacts at the boarder. But with transparent areas you can see the overlap. A fix to this can be found at [Untitled Block transparency (Beamer)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317489/untitled-block-transparency-beamer/317845#317845)