# How to add vertical spaces automatically?

Tags: macros

I am preparing a questionnaire. I want two questions to appear on each page. I adjust the gap between the first question and the second question with \vspace {6cm}, and after the second question, I switch to the new page with \newpage command and this will continue for pages like this. Is there an efficient way to do this?
[image]

```
    \documentclass[14pt]{extbook}
    \usepackage[turkish]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage{newfile}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newoutputstream{solutions}
\openoutputfile{\jobname.solutions}{solutions}
\newcounter{exblock}
\newcounter{exquestion}
\newcounter{exsubquestion}
\newlist{questionlist}{enumerate}{1}
\newlist{solutionlist}{enumerate}{1}
\newlist{subquestionlist}{enumerate*}{1}
\newlist{subsolutionlist}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[questionlist,solutionlist]{label=\arabic*.}
\setlist[subquestionlist,subsolutionlist]{label=(\alph*),itemjoin={},before=~}
\newcommand{\exheader}{%
    \ifthenelse{\value{exblock}>0}{\addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\end{solutionlist}}}{}%
    \refstepcounter{exblock}%
    \setcounter{exquestion}{0}%
    \section{Exercises}%
    \label{ex.\arabic{exblock}}%
    \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\paragraph{Exercise \noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}}, sayfa \noexpand\pageref{ex.\arabic{exblock}}}}%
    \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\begin{solutionlist}}%
}
\newcommand{\printsolutions}{%
    \ifthenelse{\value{exblock}>0}{\addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\end{solutionlist}}}{}%
    \closeoutputstream{solutions}%
    \input{\jobname.solutions}%
}
\newenvironment{exercises}[1][]{%
    \begin{questionlist}[start=\value{exquestion}+1, #1]%
}{%
    \end{questionlist}%
}
\newenvironment{exercisescol}[2][]{%
    \begin{multicols}{#2}%
    \begin{questionlist}[start=\value{exquestion}+1, #1]%
}{%
    \end{questionlist}%
    \end{multicols}%
}
\newcommand{\question}[2]{%
    \refstepcounter{exquestion}%
    \label{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exquestion}}%
    \item #1%
    \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\item[\noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exquestion}}.] #2}%
}
\newenvironment{subquestions}[1][]{%
    \refstepcounter{exquestion}%
    \label{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exquestion}}%
    \setcounter{exsubquestion}{0}%
    \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\item[\noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exquestion}}.]\noexpand\begin{subsolutionlist}}%
    \item #1%
    \begin{subquestionlist}%
}{%
    \end{subquestionlist}%
    \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\end{subsolutionlist}}
}
\newcommand{\subquestion}[2]{%
    \refstepcounter{exsubquestion}%
    \item #1%
    \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\item #2}%
}


\setlist*[questionlist]{font=\bfseries}
\setlist*[solutionlist]{noitemsep,font=\bfseries}
\setlist*[subquestionlist]{font=\bfseries}
\setlist*[subsolutionlist]{noitemsep,font=\bfseries,itemjoin={\\},before={}}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%-----------------------End of Exercises -----------------------------%


\begin{document}


\exheader
\begin{exercises}
\question{First Question}{First Answer}

\vspace{6cm}

\question{Second Question}{Second Answer}

\newpage

\question{Third Question}{Third Answer}

\vspace{6cm}

\question{Fourth Question}{Fourth Answer}

\newpage






    \end{exercises}
    
    \chapter{Answers}
    \printsolutions
    
    
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: As is, it could be simply  add some like  `\vspace*{.4\textheight}`  after `\item #1` in `\question` definition, But I guess that in the real document with different contents in each question this will be not a good idea. A better approach could be make the questions a [box with minimal height](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215442/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-parbox-to-a-minimum-height).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Is it possible to write an if block? For example if question number is odd \vspace{6cm} else \nextpage

Comment: Why?  If each question is a block with enough big,  it will produce automatic breaks every two questions. However, my advice is not fix the block size but use a generous  but flexible `\parskip` between the boxes, and a normal `\parskip` whitin the boxes, so it could be more or less question per page depending on the contents.

Comment: \parskip wont help since there will be more than one questions on some pages while there will be single question on some pages. Your first suggestion was helpful. I will use \newpage command after \item#1 for questions that should be placed on one page. However, I dont know how to write macros. It would be very helfpful if I could add some space after odd numbered questions and newpage after even numbered questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added `\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{exquestion}}}{\vspace{6cm}}{\newpage}`before  `\addtostream{solutions}...`in question definition, also I have added `\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{exquestion}}}{\vspace{6cm}}{\newpage}`before  `\addtostream{solutions}`in subquestion definition. And it worked!