# tikzcd inside parbox

Tags: tikz-cd, parbox

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\parbox{\textwidth}{\[
    \begin{tikzcd}
        a \arrow{r}{} & b
    \end{tikzcd}
\]}

\end{document}
```

The MWE above throws a bunch of errors (`Undefined control sequence` and `Package pgf: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode`), and I don't understand why. All kinds of math environments work fine inside `\parbox`, and `\tikz` seems to work too. Is this "expected behavior", or a bug?

Comment: If you use `minipage`, the problem does not appear.

Comment: But what's the reason for such a `\parbox`?

Comment: @egreg it's somewhat convoluted: I tried using @David Carlisle's [answer to making boxes with minimum height](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215445/170958) and use it to make `textblock`s (from the [`textpos`](https://ctan.org/pkg/textpos) package) with minimum height, and so a lot of stuff is being put into a single `parbox`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to nested `tikz-cd` inside `\parbox` you need replace ampersands with something else. For example as is done in MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\parbox{\textwidth}%
{
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
a \rar  \& b
    \end{tikzcd}
 \]
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For details see *20.5 Considerations Concerning Active Characters*, page 327 in Ti*k*Z & PGF manual, version 3.1.9a.

Comment: Thanks so much, that would've surely taken me ages to figure out!

Comment: @steve, you are welcome!